Void Linux зависает на "Deactivating crypt volumes"
Недавно решил установить Void Linux на два своих ноутбука - Acer и MSI.
Странно то, что на разных ноутбуках одни и те же проблемы.
Во время загрузки Live системы она зависает на Bluetooth устройстве hci0, а через минуту я получаю сообщение от udevd:
"udevd[666]: worker [669] /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 is taking a long time"
После входа в систему на MSI где-то через 30 секунд меня выкидывает из сессии, падают иксы.
После выключения система зависает намертво на третьей стадии runit - "Deactivating crypt volumes"
Помогает только удержание кнопки выключения.
Пробовал разные ISO, проверял хэшсуммы. Ничего не помогло. В интернете ровно 0 ответов.
